# In Crete, Greece around mid-late 1940's photos with the stamped on the back "A M Crown Copyright Reserved"?

Tags: history, archival

I have a few old photos from about the mid to late 1940's in Crete, Greece (the civil war occurred during the time). There is a specific stamp on the back of two photos which is marked A M Crown Copyright Reserved. Any guesses why only the children were photographed by the British photographers?

One photo is a family (my relatives) who were kids and teenagers then, standing close together looking straight into the camera as if they were told to stand like that with their arms down next to their sides. They were not smiling. And a few looked "concerned" in the photos. Before recently, I thought it was a "family" photo. But now I am not so sure. Maybe it was a family photo.

Furthermore, the other small picture I have with the same stamp on the back is only of the small boy from the other photo. He is standing in front of some kind of painted or printed mural on a cloth backdrop that shows a scene of a column, stairs, stair rails, and a wooden look image in the back of a wall.

I did some research and all I could find is that the British forces and photographers were in Greece at that time and it wasn't the best of times.

I found this info:
"The A crown M was the copyright mark of the Air Ministry, now ministry of Defence.
I was a photographer in the RAF and all photographs had to be stamped on the reverse
[https://www.ephotozine.com/forums/topic/crown-c..."](https://www.ephotozine.com/forums/topic/crown-c...%22)

Comment: Hi mkkm and welcome to Photo.SE! I see you're new to the stackexchange format, so feel free [to take the tour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how you can use this site optimally.
Currently I don't fully understand the question you have. Are you interested in why only children were photographed by the British? Or are you interested in the photos itself? In that latter case it might help to include (a link to) the photos in the post instead of describing them with words. You can [edit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/123052/edit) your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to attach an image to my question rather than a link? For my question that I posted, I have a couple of photos with that stamp on the back and the front are children only (relatives). I found out that stamp was used by British photographers who were in Crete, Greece at the time. But I am not sure why they would take photos of children only.

Comment: [This page explains how to upload an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/222653). The system might deem your reputation too low, in that case just post the link in your question and one of the other users will embed it. However, before you put in the effort to write a question, could you please check if you think your question [falls within the scope of the current site](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? If it is really about the historic aspect rather than the photographic, I would suggest to post your question on the [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you for link to the history site. I appreciate it.

Comment: If the link weren't dead already I'd embed the image. @SaaruLindestøkke Historical aspects of photography are *expressly* on topic here.

Comment: The link is probably not dead, just a copy/paste error. I saw that "history of photography" is on topic here, but I interpreted the current question as referring to the history of British forces in Greece, with coincidentally a photographic aspect (the photo could just as well be a newspaper article, a diary note, etc...). I didn't vote to close, so I think it just needs some editing to clarify the history of photography aspect.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I see the OP has [posted on History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/63254/1343) (and got an upvote).